# "Ocultar" uma célula de uma tabela

Tags: html, css, html5

Estava tentar fazer um layout simples no qual a versão desktop tem um logo no centro da main-nav no topo da página, ladeado pela navegação. Utilizar uma tabela é a melhor solução?

Tentei com DIVS, colocando o logo com 1 posição absoluta, mas quando passo para a versão de mobile não o consigo ocultar.

Envio 1 imagens com o que pretendia fazer.

[image: Obrigado pela ajuda.]

Comment: Não sei o que você quer dizer com o exemplo ladeado pela navegação. Não use tabela para montar a estrutura do seu site, pode ser realizado da melhor forma com uso das ´DIV´.

Comment: Coloca o seu código atual na pergunta. :D

Answer (score 2):

> “Ocultar” uma célula de uma tabela

Ocultar mantendo o espaço ocupado por ela:

```
td {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Ocultar o conteúdo e o espaço ocupado por ela:

```
td {
    display: none;
}
```

> Utilizar uma tabela é a melhor solução?

Não. [Use divs.](https://www.google.com.br/#q=tableless)

> Tentei com DIVS, colocando o logo com 1 posição absoluta, mas quando passo para a versão de mobile não o consigo ocultar.

Use @media-queries e priorize o layout para [dispositivos móveis](http://tableless.com.br/mobile-first-a-arte-de-pensar-com-foco/), algo como:

```css
body { margin: 0; }
nav { position: relative; }
nav li { padding:0; margin:0; }
nav ul {
  background-color: #dbf7ee;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.logo-container {
  background-color: #ee4;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.logo-container img {
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
  height: 50px; width: 50px;
}
.header-container { text-align:center; }


@media (min-width:767px){
  nav {
    background-color:#dbf7ee;
    width: 100%
  }
  nav ul {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    margin: -50px 10% 0 10%;
    position: relative;
  }
  nav ul li {
    float: left; width: 20%;
  }
  nav ul li:nth-child(3) {
    margin-left: 20%;
  }
  .logo-container img {
    margin-left: -30px;
    height:60px; width:60px;
  }
  .header-container {
    background-color: #dbf7ee;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding: 20px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo-container">
    <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/br/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=201ca43a8bd0&a">
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>Nav 1</li>
    <li>Nav 2</li>
    <li>Nav 3</li>
    <li>Nav 4</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="header-container">
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado André. Desta forma fico com o principal problema resolvido.

Comment: sabes como posso fazer para ter a terminação do header-container triangular? 

Adicionei lhe estas linhas na versão desktop e funciona bem, mas se acrescentar na versão mobile já não funciona.

Obrigado

 .header-container {
    background-color: #dbf7ee;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding: 20px 0;
    height: 70%;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 100% 60%, 100% 0, 0 0, 0 60%);
    clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 100% 60%, 100% 0, 0 0, 0 60%);
  }